# How do I factorialize a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

When I run this code in Chrome, it reports "maximum call stack size exceeded."

http://codepen.io/tcadams9/pen/JRLyOq

```js
if (randomNum === 0 || randomNum === 1)
    return 1;
for (var i = randomNum - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
}
return factorial();

$("#button2").click(factorial);
```

Comment: is that the whole function? Plx give us the function head and the definition of random Num

Comment: If `randomNum` be 0, `for` itetate infinate.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole function. If you click the codepen link, it should have all the code.  When I used this code in chrome's console, it work, but once I try linking it to the HTML page, it messes up. I think that's where my code might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up variables with DOM elements there. A DOM elements value with id "randomNum" does not equal the variable `randomNum`. To get the value, you need to `$("#randomNum").val()`.
This seems to be a mix of a recursive and a non-recursive approach. You need to clean that up: 
**Explicit:**

```
randomNum = 6; //set the value before

function factorial () {
    var num =1;
    for (var i = randomNum - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        num *= i;
    }
    return num;
}
```

and

```
$("#button2").click(function () {
  randomNumber = $("#randomNumber").val();
  $("#Factorial").html(
    factorial()
  )
})
```

or
**Recursive**

```
function factorial (randomNum) {
    if (randomNum === 0 || randomNum === 1)
        return 1;
    return randomNum * factorial(randomNum-1);
}
```

however, you can't call that function via 'click' as it wont have a `randomNumber` argument given.
To fix that, you need to change the registration of the evenHandler to

```
$("#button2").click(function () {
  $("#Factorial").html(
    factorial($("#randomNumber").val())
  )
})
```

Tested that, it worked fine.